# Mocking mongo queries

Tags: java, mongodb, mocking

I want to mock my queries to a mongo collection and confirm that the right parameters are being set in the query.

The code being tested is

```
Bson query = eq("name",name);
if (version!=null) {
    query = and(query,eq("version",version));
}
Document retrievedDoc =  collection.find(query).sort(descending("version")).first();
```

and the test I want to write is

```
Bson query = and(eq("name","test.TestClass"),eq("version",1));
when(collection.find(<some matcher>).thenReturn(result);
```

however Bson doesn't implement equals and it doesn't have any obvious methods to get any of it's contents to write a custom matcher with or to test a captured Bson with.

I'm using mockito although I don't think it matters.

Is there any nice way to assert anything more about the query than it's class?

Comment: I'll add that I am interested in any solution that allows for testability of the querying even if ti involves significant refactoring

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, too.
Since Bson doesn't implement equals, I just use org.bson.Document instead of Bson.

Here how I do it:

```
Document query = new Document("name",name);
if (version!=null) {
    query = new Document("$and", asList(query, new Document("version",version)));
}
Document retrievedDoc =  collection.find(query).sort(descending("version")).first();
```

and the test should be like:

```
Document query = new Document("$and", asList(new Document("name","test.TestClass"), new Document("version",1)));
when(collection.find(query).thenReturn(result);
```